# Knockout value binding is not updated correctly

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, coffeescript

I start creating and editable table with knockout based on this example:

`http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/8FMPc/light/`

I rewrite it using coffeescript just for readability porpuse. this is my version.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjdLu7u6/8/

However the first time the table is initialize when you click the pencil to edit the the cell the input text show no value just and empty input.

Once you input a value and click the check, whenever you tried to edit the cell it show the correct edit value in the text input.

The fact that the second time works correctly it shows that the inputs are apply correctly just seems to be a problem in how knckout update the value binding the first tieme.

NOTES:
 The beginEdit function set the self.EditValue the first time so the binding in the input text already exist the fist time is loaded, it also exists the value when you click the check because that invoke the update function that update the value with property.editValue and that value is not blank, it just seems that knockout just not display the value because it exits.

Coffescript

```
            ko.observable.fn.beginEdit = (transaction) ->
                self = this
                commitSubscription
                rollbackSubscription

                #Get the current value and store it for editing
                if(self.slice)
                    self.editValue = ko.observableArray(self.slice())
                 else
                     self.editValue = ko.observable(self())

                self.dispose = () ->         
                    #kill this subscriptions
                    commitSubscription.dispose()
                    rollbackSubscription.dispose()

                self.commit =  () ->
                    # update the actual value with the edit value
                    self(self.editValue())

                    #dispose the subscriptions
                    self.dispose();


                self.rollback =  () ->
                    #rollback the edit value
                    self.editValue(self());

                    #dispose the subscriptions
                    self.dispose();

                #subscribe to the transation commit and reject calls
                commitSubscription = transaction.subscribe(self.commit, self, "commit");

                rollbackSubscription = transaction.subscribe(self.rollback, self, "rollback");

                return self;

            class Team
                constructor : (name) ->
                    @id = ko.observable(null)
                    @name = ko.observable(name)
                    @students = ko.observableArray([])
                    @activityGroup = ko.observableArray([])
                    @delivery = ko.observableArray([])
                reset : () ->
                    @id(null)
                    @name(null)
                    @students(null)
                    @activityGroup(null)
                    @delivery(null)
                beginEdit : (transaction) ->
                    @name.beginEdit(transaction)

            class TeamViewModel
                constructor : () ->
                    @teams = ko.observableArray([])
                    @editingItem = ko.observable()

                    #create the transaction for commit and reject
                    @editTransaction = new ko.subscribable()

                isItemEditing : (item) ->
                        return item == @editingItem()

                editItem : (item) ->
                    if ( @editingItem() == null) 
                         console.log("Entra")
                        #start the transaction
                        item.beginEdit(@editTransaction)

                        #shows the edit fields
                        @editingItem(item)

                applyItem : (item) ->
                    #commit the edit transaction
                    @editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "commit")

                    #hides the edit fields
                    @editingItem(null)

                cancelEdit : (item) ->
                    #reject the edit transaction
                    @editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "rollback")

                    #hides the edit fields
                    @editingItem(null)



            $(document).ready(() ->
                model = new  TeamViewModel()
                initData = [
                    new Team("Team Name")            
                ]
                model.teams(initData)
                ko.applyBindings( model );
            );
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: teams">
                    <aside class="profile-nav alt">
                        <section class="panel">
                            <div class="user-heading alt gray-bg"> <a href="#">
                                 <img src="images/lock_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
                             </a>

                                 <h1>
                                     <span data-bind="text: name, visible: !$root.isItemEditing($data)"></span>
                                     <input type="text"  data-bind="value: name.editValue, visible: $root.isItemEditing($data)"  />
                                     <i class="fa fa-pencil" data-bind="click: $root.editItem.bind($root), visible: !$root.isItemEditing($data)"></i>
                                     <i class="fa fa-check" data-bind="click: $root.applyItem.bind($root), visible: $root.isItemEditing($data)"></i>

                                 </h1>

                                <p>Nombre del lider</p>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Mail Inbox <span class="badge label-success pull-right r-activity">10</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Recent Activity <span class="badge label-danger pull-right r-activity">15</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i> Notification <span class="badge label-success pull-right r-activity">11</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Message <span class="badge label-warning pull-right r-activity">03</span></a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                    </aside>
                </div>
```

Comment: I create a new version in javascript http://jsfiddle.net/sjdLu7u6/9/